# SSAS process error "Parser: The end of the input was reached" just on powershell deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, ssas, ssas-2012

I have created a deployment script with the Deployment Wizard.
When I execute the xmla in Management Studio I can process the whole SSAS database without an error. When I execute the script with powershell I am getting the error message

"Parser: The end of the input was reached"

when I process the DB.

Any ideas?

Thanks 
Andi

Comment: Do you mean with Invoke-ASCmd? There is a bug in which it is unclear if has been fixed http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/746454/invoke-ascmd-fails-when-queries-contain-the-word-go#details

Comment: I tried it by this function:
...
    [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.xmla.xmlaclient]$xmlac = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.XmlaClient  
    $xmlac.Connect($ServerInstance)  
    $properties = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],     [System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"  
    $xmlac.Send($query, $properties);  
    $xmlac.Disconnect();  
...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.